# What do you call something that's the inverse of something?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call something that's the inverse of something? I am asking, because there are many different ways something can be the inverse of something, but what if inverse meant for example "opposite of X and opposite of Y" as in "tall and arrogant" versus "short and humble"?

For example:

> The man is tall and arrogant and the ___ of that would be much better
>   for this movie role.

I think "inverse" and "opposite" can fit here, but is there a more serious word or phrase for it? I am thinking of writing an essay and I can't remember a phrase or a word that can substitute it. "Opposite" and "inverse" sound too informal, although the example sentence is informal too when it should have been formal.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no regular way to define "opposite" so it applies to anything. Opposition is always in a dimension, like _up/down_ or _big/small_; but most words have a number of dimensions, and they may not be opposable. What is the opposite of _thumb_, for example -- _finger_ or _great toe_? What is the opposite of _nose_? And if _opposite_ is vague, _inverse, converse,_ and _contrapositive_ are incomprehensible.

Comment: Any number of synonyms could work. What you have looked at, rejected, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you call something that's the inverse of something?

I am not quite sure what you are looking for as there are a few alternative answers. A noun would be **oposite** or from your description, possibly more accurately would be **exact opposite**. It could also be **flip side**

However, we could also use **idioms** like

**like chalk and cheese, Yin and Yang, mirror image, poles apart, the other side of the coin.**

I think the most commonly used phrase would be **the complete opposite**

> I'm nothing more than what you actually see, but I am also **the complete opposite**.
>   Keren Ann
>
> In the old days rank was not important - **The complete opposite** of today. You just trained
>   Higa Yuchoku
>
> People have this idea of me being some kind of monster, and that's **the complete opposite** of who I am.
>   PJ Harvey

Reference

> **inverse** noun: something of a contrary nature or quality : **OPPOSITE**, >**REVERSE** [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inverse)
>
> **exact opposite** noun Definition of exact opposite: **the complete opposite**
>
> He used to be romantic, but now he's the exact opposite.[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exact%20opposite)